# Visualize data during experiment: Gazebo/RVIZ

Tags: gazebo, navigation, simulation, rviz, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My current setup involves

- 3 robots with pandaboards
- a server with camera

The server handles the core and the absolute positioning software running off the camera which publishes the robots' transforms.

On a laptop I run RVIZ and am able to visualize position and orientation of the robots.

Now what I would like to do is visualize other things like:

- walls
- objects
- objectives
- other data

[image: image description]

I would like to visualize the walls (and floor) of the laboratory to get a decent picture, and I would really like a way to see the vectors I send the robots somehow or, having implemented a holonomic controller, I'd really like to see the control point move about in RVIZ to check if the robot is indeed doing what it's supposed to.

How can I achieve this?
RVIZ seems limited in term of visualization, while GAZEBO seems suited for simulation but not visualization.

Any other option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57267/visualize-data-during-experiment:-gazebo/rviz/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few options that you can look into:

- You can use some of the built-in rviz display types like the Path, Polygon or Pose displays for a lot of data (for example representing walls by polygon lines)
- Otherwise, the
  [Marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker)
  display is intended for such tasks.
  It allows to easily use quite a few
  primitives and also supports
  displaying meshes (You could build
  arbitrary complex meshes using Blender
  and just display them as markers)
- If these options do not offer what
  you'd like to have, you always have
  the option to write your own rviz
  visualization plugin. Some good
  examples of such plugins are part of
  MoveIt ([Link to
  plugins](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/tree/groovy-devel/visualization)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3